# How to use gpg without --keyserver (which is deprecated too, just like apt-key)

Tags: debian, bash, gpg

#### The background

For some time now, `apt-key` warn users with deprecated messages like this one:

> use of apt-key is deprecated, except for the use of apt-key del in maintainer scripts to remove existing keys from the main keyring

There is a lot of documentation online (on SE network and elsewhere) about "fixing" those `apt-key` warning by using `gpg` directly. For instance:

```bash
curl -sS <https://example.com/key/repo-key.gpg> | sudo apt-key add -
```

can be replaced by

```bash
curl -sS <https://example.com/key/repo-key.gpg> | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/<repo>-archive-keyring.gpg
```

in order to avoid deprecated errors.

---

### The issue

In Debian, sometimes we need to add Ubuntu PPA. We usually do something like:

```bash
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com XXXXXX
```

that can become either of:

```bash
# something like
gpg --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com XXXXXX

# or something like
sudo gpg --no-default-keyring \
  --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/<myrepository>-archive-keyring.gpg \
  --keyserver <hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80> \
  --recv-keys <fingerprint>
```

but there is a catch: **gpg `--keyserver` option is also deprecated!**

```
--keyserver name
    This option is deprecated
```

---

### The question

How can we add an Ubuntu PPA on Debian 11 without using the deprecated gpg `--keyserver` option?

If that matter, my purpose is using it inside a script or an automation tool like ansible, so I would prefer to avoid manuals or GUI steps.

---

### See also / Related

- https://dev.gnupg.org/T4512
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679495/now-that-apt-key-is-deprecated-how-do-you-add-an-ubuntu-ppa-as-a-debian-apt-sou <= in my opinion this is **not a duplicate**, as the most rated answer doesn't provide a solution for the gpg `--keyserver` deprecation
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-handle-apt-key-and-add-apt-repository-deprecation-using-gpg-to-add-external-repositories-on-ubuntu-22-04
- https://itsfoss.com/apt-key-deprecated/
- https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/01/apt-key-is-deprecated-how-to-add.html
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545/what-commands-exactly-should-replace-the-deprecated-apt-key
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328806/how-to-solve-apt-key-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Read further, as the sentence on the [gpg(1)](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/gpg/gpg.1.en.html) continues...

> **--keyserver** *name*
>
> This option is deprecated - please use the **--keyserver** in ‘*dirmngr.conf*’ instead.

If you are running GnuPG with `sudo` i.e. as *root*, you should configure it in `/root/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf`, otherwise in `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf`:

```
keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com
no-use-tor
```

*The additional `no-use-tor` prevents GnuPG from trying to use Tor for the key retrieval, which is its default operation.*